# List of dates (Every 2 weeks) that includes the first of the month as well

Tags: date, if-statement, google-sheets, filter, array-formulas

I am trying to come up with a simple formula that I can extend infinitely to show me a list of dates that is separated by 2 weeks (14 days) and also includes the first of the month.  The 2 weeks part is easy to accomplish with:

```
=A2+14
```

Where A2 has a date in the field to start the calculations.  Then I can extend that down the column to have:

```
=A3+14
=A4+14
```

And so on...  The hard part is, I also want to include the first of each month.  So the list should include every other Friday and the first of the month dynamically.  So the results would be like this:

```
2/28/2020
3/01/2020
3/13/2020
3/27/2020
4/01/2020
4/10/2020
```

As you can see from this list, it looks at every other Friday AND the first of the month is included in the results.  I tried something like this:

```
=IF(MONTH(A3+14)>MONTH(A3),eomonth(A3+14,-1)+1,A2+14)
```

The issue from this one is that if the first of the month condition gets selected, the next date is 14 days AFTER the first of the month.  It should be 14 days after the previous Friday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(UNIQUE({
 EOMONTH(ROW(INDIRECT(C1&":"&C2)), 0)+1; 
 FILTER(ROW(INDIRECT(C1&":"&C2)), 
 MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&DAYS(C2, C1)+1)), 14)=0)+1})))
```

[image]

Comment: The results look good, but is it possible to not use the C1 and C2 references?  I tried replacing them with actual dates, but it is complaining about the Index values.

Comment: That works!  Only thing that confuses me now is the last part of it.  I changed it to A2:A because I want to start it on the 2nd row (first row has headers), but when I do that, it changes everything to ONLY show the first of the month dates.  Not sure what is causing that behavior.

Comment: Got it, I needed to change the +1 to a +2 on the final part.  Thanks!

Comment: you dont need to change it to A2:A. regardless where you put it (row1, row2, row27) it should always reed A1:A because this is MOD calculation (eg. it has nothing to do with row where formula is located)